# Root Test Using Ln()?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Root test for $$A_n:\sum\frac n{n^2+1}.$$

When we take limit of the function, I know that $n^{1/n}$ is going to $1$.

But what happens to the denominator? As I understand, an $\ln()$ trick is used.

Comment: Are you really required to use the root test here?  $\dfrac n{n^2+1}$ is not a good fit for the root test.

Comment: I realize that, but unfortunately yes

Comment: Something that is not the integral test, comparison, or limit test would also work but I still would like to know how this method is used

Comment: The root test can't be used here, because it gives $1$. I don't see how to use a trick with $\ln$ to escape this fact.

Comment: Not the integral test or comparison or limit test, the only thing that comes to mind aside from the root test is the ratio test.  But the ratio test is also inconclusive.  Maybe there's a test I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you insist on using the root test?

If not, then you could do a limit comparison 
$$
a_n = \frac{n}{n^2+1} \\
b_n = \frac{1}{n}
$$
Here, of course, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.

If you do insist on the root test, then to find
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} y
$$
where $y = \sqrt[n]{n^2+1}$ it indeed will work if you let $\ln(y) = \frac{1}{n}\ln(n^2 + 1)$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(n^2 + 1)}{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2n/(n^2 + 1)}{1} = 0
$$
So
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} y = 1.
$$
In all the Root test gives you a limit of $1$, so it doesn't work.

Comment: wouldnt it be 1/0?

Comment: @mathguy: No $\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln(y) = 0$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}  y = 1$.

Comment: I am a bit confused on how you got the 2n/(n^2+1)

Comment: @mathguy: L'Hopital's rule

Comment: ok I get that part but if it is 1/(ln(n^2+1) / n) wouldnt that = n / ln(n^2 + 1)

Comment: @mathguy: I don't understand. You are wanting to use the Root Test and you have a fraction. You have noted that the numerator goes to $1$ and now you can show that the denominator goes to $1$ as well. So in all you get $1$.

Comment: Oh so you used ln of the entire function? not just the denominator

Comment: @mathguy: No, I just found the limit of the denominator because you had already realized what the numerator approaches.

Comment: well if the limit of the denominator = 0 and the numerator approaches 1 then isnt that 1/0?

Comment: @mathguy: But I showed that the limit of the denominator is $1$ :)

Answer (score 3):

The root test says to examine the value of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty} |A_n|^{1/n}$, where in this case, $A_n = \dfrac n{n^2+1}$.

Let's use the fact that $$ \lim_{n\to+\infty} |A_n|^{1/n} = \lim_{x\to+\infty} |f(x)|^{1/x},$$
where $f(x) = \dfrac x{x^2+1}$ is differentiable and satisfies $f(n) = A_n$.  This allows us to then do this:
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\to+\infty} |A_n|^{1/n} &= \lim_{x\to+\infty} |f(x)|^{1/x}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{x\to+\infty} \left( \frac x{x^2+1} \right)^{1/x} \\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{x\to+\infty} \exp\left[\ln\left( \frac x{x^2+1} \right)^{1/x}\right] \\[0.3cm]
    &= \exp\left[\lim_{x\to+\infty} \ln\left( \frac x{x^2+1} \right)^{1/x}\right] \\[0.3cm]
    &= \exp\left[\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac1x \ln\left( \frac x{x^2+1} \right)\right]
\end{align*}
Now, since direct evaluation of the limit inside the $\exp$ gives us $-\infty/\infty$, this tells us we can use l'Hopital's rule.  So let's do that.
\begin{align*}
  \exp\left[\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac1x \ln\left( \frac x{x^2+1} \right)\right]  &= \exp\left[\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\ln x - \ln(x^2+1)}x\right]\\[0.3cm]
    &= \exp\left[\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\frac1x - \frac{2x}{x^2+1}}1\right]\\[0.3cm]
    &= \exp(0)\\
    &= 1
\end{align*}
So the root test is inconclusive because $\lim_{n\to+\infty} |A_n|^{1/n} = 1$.